# Mysql array numbers for a raffle php

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table for raffles (id, name, activated ..etc) and one for the raffle numbers (each must be ticket 00100-400000, tickets 4000 total) but I have a doubt: do I have to create a table for each raffle?

Must each raffle have a table that contains the numbers 4000 ticket or can I put them in a row containing numbers of tickets?  The numbers must have an id and an on or off.

```
[raffles_table]
|id|name       |  state(active or off)|

 25  rafle-car          1



[number_table]

[id|idrafle|numberoftiket|state]
 1     25     00100           1
```

Comment: as sergio suggested. look into a relational architecture for your DB.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help, I will try what it says Sergio Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not create a table for each raffle.

Your best bet is

```
=======      =======
RAFFLES      TICKETS
=======      =======
id           id
name         number
...          id_raffle
             ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sergio, I'll focus in this way: D